# Which buffer quickfix file is opened in?

Tags: buffers, quickfix

One thing that drives me crazy is unpredictable quickfix behaviour.

Say I am editing a file, then I split the window and would like to find something and open in that buffer.

I use `:Ag whatever` to fill the QuickFix and press `Enter` on the search result.

Expected:

File is opened in the split I use before going to QuickFix.

Actual:

File is opened in any split on the screen.

Am I missing something?

I know that you can search first and split after. I usually keep many buffers open to see the whole chain of calls/requires and I would like to insert buffers in between other ones.

Answer (score 8):

This is a fairly widespread and well-known annoyance.  There are at least two plugins which aim to address it: [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) and [QFEnter](https://github.com/yssl/QFEnter)

But, the behavior is quite predictable (cf `:help quickfix.txt`).  If the file is already open, vim switches to it and moves to the correct line/column. Otherwise, the window directly above the quickfix window is used (and the buffer is replaced).

So aside from living with the possibly unintuitive default behavior, you have a few options:

- remap `<cr>` (or anything else) in the quickfix window to do something else, for example opening the item in the previous window. Example:
  `autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <cr> :exe 'wincmd p \| '.line('.').'cc'<cr>`
- use a plugin which makes similar maps
- only ever use `:cc`, `:cnext`, and `:cprev`, which operate in the current window (although this would require`set switchbuf=`)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [`ag.vim`](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) which is  [depecrated](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim/issues/124#issuecomment-227038003)? You should try [`ack.vim`](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim#can-i-use-ag-the-silver-searcher-with-this).

Other than that, are you sure that the expected window is focused?

I have these settings in my vimrc to make the split direction more "natural":

```
set splitbelow " Split windows below the current window
set splitright " Split windows right of the current window
```

**Edit**: From the [`quickfix-window`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-window) help:

> The file containing the error is opened in the window above the
>   quickfix window.  If there already is a window for that file, it is used
>   instead.

It seems to open the file in the *bottom right split* every time, not the last used.

Comment: Actually I am using `vim-grepper`.  Just kept the same command because it uses `ag` anyway. The question is how Quickfix decides in which buffer it will open the file?